# Display rotation of vector over time with ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector

I have a grid of wind vectors that rotate over time. I have the `u` and `v` components (east-west and north-south) of these vectors.

Here is an example overlaying the vectors from all times at one grid point.

```
quiver(zeros((8,1)), zeros((8,1)),u[:,1,1], v[:,1,1])
```

[image]

I would like to summarize the rotation of these vectors in one plot, by plotting ellipses at each grid point that basically trace the path of the vector over time.

I am basically looking to do what is done in this plot here:
[image]
https://mdc.coaps.fsu.edu/scatterometry/meeting/docs/2015/NewProductsAndApplications/gille_ovwst15.pdf

*The ellipses are slightly faint, but they're there.*

I'm guessing I should use `matplotlib.patches.ellipse` somehow, but I'm not sure how to get the ellipse angle out of my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main components to this problem.

1. **Fitting an ellipse**.
   There is actually a nice example on how to fit an ellipse to data points in python found on [this site](http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html). So we can use this to obtain the rotation angle as well as the 2 dimensions of the ellipse from the data.
2. **Plotting all ellipses to a figure**. Once the ellipse parameters are obtained, an ellipse can be plotted using [`matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse)

Here is the complete code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import eig, inv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

######################
### Ellipse fitting ##
######################
# taken from 
# http://nicky.vanforeest.com/misc/fitEllipse/fitEllipse.html

def fitEllipse(x,y):
    x = x[:,np.newaxis]
    y = y[:,np.newaxis]
    D =  np.hstack((x*x, x*y, y*y, x, y, np.ones_like(x)))
    S = np.dot(D.T,D)
    C = np.zeros([6,6])
    C[0,2] = C[2,0] = 2; C[1,1] = -1
    try:
        E, V =  eig(np.dot(inv(S), C))
        n = np.argmax(np.abs(E))
        a = V[:,n]
        return a
    except:
        return [np.nan]*5

def ellipse_center(a):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    num = b*b-a*c
    x0=(c*d-b*f)/num
    y0=(a*f-b*d)/num
    return np.real(np.array([x0,y0]))


def ellipse_angle_of_rotation( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    return np.real(0.5*np.arctan(2*b/(a-c)))


def ellipse_axis_length( a ):
    b,c,d,f,g,a = a[1]/2, a[2], a[3]/2, a[4]/2, a[5], a[0]
    up = 2*(a*f*f+c*d*d+g*b*b-2*b*d*f-a*c*g)
    down1=(b*b-a*c)*( (c-a)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    down2=(b*b-a*c)*( (a-c)*np.sqrt(1+4*b*b/((a-c)*(a-c)))-(c+a))
    res1=np.sqrt(up/down1)
    res2=np.sqrt(up/down2)
    return np.real(np.array([res1, res2]))


########################
### Data Generation  ###
########################

n_el = 8 # number of ellipse points
# define grid
x = np.linspace(-7,7, 15)
y = np.linspace(4,18, 15)
# data (2 for x,y (west, north), n_el, dimensions of grid in x and y )
data = np.zeros((2, n_el,len(x), len(y) )) 
for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        #generate n_el points on an ellipse 
        r = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, n_el) 
        data[0,:,j,i]  = 0.5*(0.9*np.random.random(1)+0.1) * np.cos(r+2*np.random.random(1)*np.pi) 
        data[1,:,j,i] =  0.5*(0.9*np.random.random(1)+0.1) * np.sin(r)

# Test case: fit an ellipse and print the parameters
a = fitEllipse(data[0,:,0,0], data[1,:,0,0])
ang = ellipse_angle_of_rotation(a)
l = ellipse_axis_length( a )
center = ellipse_center(a)
print "\tangle: {}\n\tlength: {}\n\tcenter: {}".format(ang, l, center)




######################
####### plotting   ###
######################
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(11,5))

# First, draw the test case ellipse
# raw data
ax.scatter(data[0,:,0,0], data[1,:,0,0], s=30, c="r", zorder=10)

# Fitted Ellipse 
# matplotlib.patches.Ellipse
# http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Ellipse
# takes width and height as diameter instead of half width and rotation in degrees
e = Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=2*l[0], height=2*l[1], angle=ang*180./np.pi,  facecolor="b", alpha=0.2, zorder=0 )
ec = Ellipse(xy=(0,0), width=2*l[0], height=2*l[1], angle=ang*180./np.pi,  fill=False,  zorder=1 )
ax.add_artist(e)
ax.add_artist(ec)

ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_xlim([-1,1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])  

# Fit ellipse for every datapoint on grid and place in figure
for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        a = fitEllipse(data[0,:,j,i], data[1,:,j,i])
        ang = ellipse_angle_of_rotation(a)
        l = ellipse_axis_length( a )
        e = Ellipse(xy=(x[j],y[i]), width=2*l[0], height=2*l[1], angle=ang*180./np.pi, fill=False, zorder=1 )
        ax2.add_artist(e)

ax2.set_ylim([y.min()-0.5, y.max()+0.5 ])
ax2.set_xlim([x.min()-0.5, x.max()+0.5 ])
ax2.set_aspect("equal")

# load some background image.
image = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/ca/Singapore-OutlineMap-20050606.png/600px-Singapore-OutlineMap-20050606.png"
image = np.rot90(plt.imread(image))
im = ax2.imshow(image,extent=[x.min()-0.5, x.max()+0.5, y.min()-0.5, y.max()+0.5, ] )        

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This works great. Do you know of any way to add arrowheads onto the ellipses, to indicate direction or rotation?